# How to save value to custom fields in sales_shipment_item table?

Tags: magento2

I have added custom fields in `sales_shipment_item` table. I just want to save a value in that custom fields on a particular event.
How can I do it?

Comment: in which particular event would you like to add the value to custom fields?

Comment: on ready for dispatch . I call a funtction in which i just want to save value in custom fields.

Comment: can you post your function? let's see how we can make it work

Comment: Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Shipment\Item is the class which is responsible for your requirement based on entity_id you can set value @kimnana

Comment: I was little bit confuse.on ready for dispatch I want to create shipment and while creating  the shipment also have save custom fields value . I dont have entity_id.

Answer (score 2):

Hi You Can do this by creating an event "sales_order_shipment_save_before"

Create a sample module Stackoverflow_Answer and follow below instruction.

> step1: Create custom fields in sales_shipment_item table as Below
>
> Create InstallSchema.php under
>   "app/code/Stackoverflow/Answer/Setup/InstallSchema.php

```
<?php

namespace Stackoverflow\Answer\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();


        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $setup->getTable('sales_shipment_item'),
            'custom_field',
            [
                'type' => Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true,
                'default' => NULL,
                'length' => 255,
                'comment' => 'Custom Field Text'
            ] 
        );

    $setup->endSetup();    
    }
}
?>
```

> step2:  create an event "sales_order_shipment_save_before"
>   Create events.xml under app/code/Stackoverflow/Answer/etc/adminhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_order_shipment_save_before">
        <observer name="stackoverflow_beforeshipment" instance="Stackoverflow\Answer\Observer\BeforeShipment" />
    </event>

</config>
```

> step3:  create observer file BeforeShipment.php under app/code/Stackoverflow/Answer/Observer

```
<?php

namespace Stackoverflow\Answer\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;    

class BeforeShipment implements ObserverInterface
{    
    protected $_logger;
    public function __construct(\Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
        foreach ($shipment->getItemsCollection() as $item) {    
                $item->setCustomField('test info');
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

[image]

I hope it helps. 
Also, I am quite confused about to do this with extension_attribute and plugin.

Comment: it doesnt  save  custm attribute value.

Comment: okay, how can i share my package so you can check. Did you faced any issue?

Comment: Its resolved using $item->setData('custom_field','test info2'); . now its workin perfectly . Thank you.

Comment: can you help  me passed dynamic data to observer and save it

Comment: Hi your solution is working perfectly . But I have lot stuffs to do , Can I call this observer after shipment Create . Thanks

Comment: Hi @kim na na, i don't think after shipment it will save value in database.

Comment: yes ! you are right , I was stuck due another stuff.. Thanks for Your time